# Modify Plot in OnReceive() of BroadcastReceiver object

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast, androidplot

I would be grateful if you could help me with the following issue.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    XYPlot plot;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Init plot.
        plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.plotView);
        // configure plot to heart's desire.
        // add XYSeries object to plot.
        // plot looks fine after activity has finished onCreate().


        // Init receiver
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("Yay", "onReceived called"); // Appears on LogCat.
                plot.setTitle("A Happy Plot"); // Doesn't take effect.
            }
        }

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(MyIntentService.NOTIFICATION));
    }



}
```

XYPlot member variable in Activity class doesn't seem to be responding to method calls invoked from said Activity's BroadcastReceiver member variable.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Try adding initialization of `plot` in `onReceive` method

Comment: I've tried initializing plot in onReceive method.  Doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not redrawing the plot after you change the title.  Try this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Yay", "onReceived called"); // Appears on LogCat.
    plot.setTitle("A Happy Plot"); // Doesn't take effect.
    plot.redraw();
}
```